# "ReferenceError: Chartkick is not defined" in Rails app - Graphs not showing after refresh

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, chartkick

Trying to include Chartkick in my Rails 6.1 application (Ruby 2.6.6). After following the instructions, I always get this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Chartkick is not defined

The charts work when I first load a page. As soon as I refresh, it only says "loading..." where the charts should be.

Most of the past answers deal with the order of when "Chartkick" is loaded, but none worked. In my case, the `require("chartkick")` is in my `app/javascript/packs/application.js` file, which gets loaded in my `layouts/appliaction.htmp.erb` file in the head with `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload', defer: true %>`

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you referencing Chartkick.  When using Rails 6.x and webpacker the `require("chartclick")` does not make the library available globally.

Comment: Thanks Ben! Can you give more context how I can fix this?

Comment: What version of Rails are you using again?

Comment: My Rails version is 6.1, Ruby 2.6.6